# Dual-Boot with Windows 11 and BitLocker

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I want to setup a dual-boot of Ubuntu with Windows 11.
Currently I am using Microsoft account and BitLocker is ON.
Do I have to do anything to be able to successfully setup the dual-boot?
Or it is straightforward and I just proceed with the Ubuntu installation?